# How to combine these 2 commands to a single command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've 2 ffmpeg commands that I want to combine.

This code adds 2 drawtext to the input video, one at the starting and one at the end.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: borderw=2: fontfile=Arial Black: fontsize=w*0.04: x=(w-text_w)-(w*0.04): y=(h-text_h)-(w*0.04): enable='between(t,0,6)', drawtext=text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: borderw=2: fontfile=Arial Black: fontsize=w*0.04: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2: enable='between(t,7,10)'[out]" -codec:a copy output2.mp4
```

and this code adds a red background to the video. I need to apply the red background to the second drawtext from 7 to 10 second.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=red:s=1280x720:d=4" -filter_complex "overlay" output.mp4
```

How to combine these two commands into a single command?

Comment: A background just over the text or a 1280x720 area?

Comment: @Gyan full screen solid background of 1280x720 area

Comment: Is video resolution 1280x720?

Comment: @Gyan Yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: borderw=2: fontfile=Arial Black: fontsize=w*0.04: x=(w-text_w)-(w*0.04): y=(h-text_h)-(w*0.04): enable='between(t,0,6)', drawbox=c=red:t=fill:enable='between(t,7,10)',drawtext=text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: borderw=2: fontfile=Arial Black: fontsize=w*0.04: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2: enable='between(t,7,10)'" -c:a copy output2.mp4
```

I just use the drawbox filter to paint the video red for the given time range, then draw text afterwards